# Check if marker Inside A Polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I know if the marker is inside a few edges or not? using https://leafletjs.com/

e.g. How to check if a marker like

```
L.marker([51.505000, -0.09000]).addTo(mymap);
```

is inside a polygon like

```
L.polygon([ [51.509, -0.08], [51.503, -0.06], [51.51, -0.047] ,[51.53, -0.047]  ]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am a polygon.");
```

Comment: If you're looking for the general math technique, there's a good walkthrough here with some sample C++ code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches for this. I would go for [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip), or in a more generic way, [TurfJS's `booleanPointInPolygon`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon), e.g.:

```
var pt = turf.point([ -0.09000, 51.505]);
var poly = turf.polygon([[
  [ -0.08, 51.509], [-0.06, 51.503], [-0.047, 51.51] ,[-0.047, 51.53]
]]);

if (turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, poly)) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Note that leaflet-pip needs instances of `L.GeoJSON`, and that TurfJS handles data in GeoJSON format. Be aware of [Leaflet's lat-long vs GeoJSON's long-lat](https://macwright.org/lonlat/).

Looking at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geoprocessing , it seems that (at the time of this writing) there are no utilities to do point-in-polygon calculations just with `L.Marker` and `L.Polygon` instances.

Comment: There is a way without using turfjs?

Comment: Yes. Note how I wrote about `leaflet-pip`.